# Extra-axiomatic true statements for proving a theorem?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

So, my question is about proving theorems and the axioms needed to prove the theorem. My understanding is that, in the theorem statement there are certain axioms and one conclusion we have to prove. We have to prove that the conclusion of the theorem statement holds given that **exactly** all of the axioms given in the theorem statement hold, no more or no less.
All of the axioms are taken to be true, we do not question them.

Now, often in the proof of the theorem, we introduce new definitions like "Let x be a factor of 4" or "Let p=q/3", etc for example. Since they are definitions (we define them), they are true. If we define them in this way and then go on to prove the theorem, does it imply that we have proved the theorem from **not** exactly the axioms (taken to be true unquestionably) given in the theorem statement, but from the axioms **plus** the definition(s) that we have stipulated? In which case, we have not *proved* the theorem properly because we are supposed to prove it from **exactly** those axioms given in the theorem statement, no more or no less.

Let me take an example. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem In the proof section of this Wikipedia article on Mean Value Theorem, the proof starts with Define g(x)= f(x) - rx. And then the theorem is proved. Now in the proof of this theorem, use has been made of the definition g(x) = f(x) - rx. So shouldn't we say that the theorem has been proved from the axioms: 1. Let f : [ a , b ] → R be a function where a < b, 2. f is continuous on [a , b], 3. f is differentiable on (a ,b), 4. g(x) = f(x) - rx, instead of the first three conditions 1, 2 and 3 (as listed above) only? Why or why not?

What am I missing out? Where have I gone wrong? I can't figure out for my life..

[I am trying to self-learn Mathematics, and am quite a beginner, so please be understanding.]

Comment: Definitions made during a proof do not affect the proof's validity. They are in a way simply shorthand, and from one's proof using the definitions, one could simply re-write the same proof but spell out the definitions whenever they are used, and the more lengthy proof does not even need the definitions.